# sum of BigDecimal List using streams and sum method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If we have all int or long or other primitive datatype value in list then we obtain sun of all values using

```
return items.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

I have list of BigDecimal values,how to find the sum of all values using `Java8`

As there is no default method like mapToBigDecimal I tried to create plain map but then I cannot use `sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
items.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Though Answer provided by Lisq199 works but I am in favor of including Holger and Klitos comments,This handles No values and always returns a value

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Stream#reduce(BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

A simple example:

```
List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
items.stream().reduce((i, j) -> i.add(j)).ifPresent(System.out::println);
// Outputs 102.5
```

Comment: Or, if you want to return 0 if the list is empty: `.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (i, j) -> i.add(j))` - this returns a BigDecimal instead of an Optional.

Comment: It is also possible to replace lambda with method reference `BigDecimal::add`, since that can be compiled into `BinaryOperator`. I would advise not to though, because in absence of `MathContext` even `add` can produce `ArithmeticExceptions`. Much safer implementation would be to choose some MathContext and use lambda that `adds` in its presence.

Comment: Since addition has a neutral element, you can use  `reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)` and don’t need to deal with `Optional`.

Comment: @ Mikhail Prokhorov: without a `MathContext`, `BigDecimal::add` will always retain all digits and never throw an `ArithmeticException`.