# How to sum a Stream of CompleteableFuture<BigDecimal> conveniently?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-stream

I'm looking for a non-blocking way to sum a Stream of `CompleteableFuture<BigDecimal>`.

I already found topics closely related to this problem, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966808/sum-of-bigdecimal-list-using-streams-and-sum-method).
But unfortunately in my case I do have the `BigDecimal` packed into a CompleteableFuture and therefore I need to wait for completion first.
In the end I would like to get another CompleteableFuture which contains the sum of all Futures within the Stream, once it's completed.

**EDIT:**
Actually I did manage to find the following solution:

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<BigDecimal>> lotOfWork;
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> lotOfWork.map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                             .reduce(
                                                 BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0), 
                                                 BigDecimal::add
                                              )
);
```

But since this is not using any of the [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) methods, I'm pretty sure there is an even better way to do this job.

Comment: [CompletableFuture.allOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) could help.

Comment: Actually there is this pretty neat method provided by ``CompleteableFuture`` called ``thenCombine`` which allows to execute a function on two previously calculated ``CompletionStages``. Unfortunately I don't have any clue how to use this within the stream.

Comment: I don't see any problem with what you have. You can slightly optimize it with the non-identity `reduce()` overload and/or the `BigDecimal.ZERO` constant.

Comment: Well, for the time being I'm happy with the solution I found. But if anyone could provide a solution using the ``CompletionStage`` interface, I'd gladly accept it. This is what makes the ``CompleteableFuture`` such a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with the CompletableFuture::thenCombine as suggested by you directly

I would have prefer a solution that does not enforce the reduction order but didn't find it in the javadoc.

```
CompletableFuture<BigDecimal> result = lotOfWork.reduce((a,b) -> a.thenCombine(b, BigDecimal::add)).orElse(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BigDecimal.ZERO));
```

Comment: After testing the solution you suggested, I noticed there is a huge increase in parallelism in my program, which makes this solution so much more powerful than mine. Unfortunately the ``reduce`` method itself is in fact blocking, while the operations done by it are being processed parallelly. This leats to a huge increase in execution speed but also blocks the GUI thread.

Comment: there is a second thenCombine with async in the name. I have no clue if it will solve your issue or not but it's probably worth trying